# how to generate output for multi-plots within a loop in shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

very simple question: I want several barplots in output,

for example: I have a dataset: data and a list of customer: cname

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
     for(name in cname){
        output[[name]] <- renderPlot({
        bp<-barplot(data[data$customer==name,1])
        })
     }
}
```

But it doesn't work, it seems the loop is not fully executed, need someone's help here.

Comment: Please provide a a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample data so we can test the code to see what might be going on. Also include a simple UI to test with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the problem you seem to be running into is related to delayed evaluation. The commands in `renderPlot()` are not executed immediately. They are captured and run when the plot is ready to be drawn. The problem is that the value of `name` is changing each iteration. By the time the plots are drawn (which is long after the for loop has completed), the `name` variable only has the last value it had in the loop.

The easiest workaround would probably be to switch from a `for` loop to using `Map`. Since `Map` calls functions, those functions create closures which capture the current value of `name` for each iteration. Try this

```
# sample data
set.seed(15)
cname <- letters[1:3]
data <- data.frame(
    vals = rpois(10*length(cname),15),
    customer = rep(cname,each=10)
)

runApp(list(server=
shinyServer(function(input, output){
     Map(function(name) {
           output[[name]] <- renderPlot({
           barplot(data[data$customer==name,1])
        })
        },
        cname)
})
,ui=
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    plotOutput("a"),
    plotOutput("b"),
    plotOutput("c")
))
))
```

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the explanations in the accepted answer. However we don't need to use a  `Map` function which is a wrapper to `mapply` i.e. a multivariate version of `sapply`  (see ?Map). In that case, we could simply use the more traditional function `lapply` :

```r
lapply(cname, function(name) {
    output[[name]] <- renderPlot({
      barplot(data[data$customer==name,1])
    })
  })
```